# Refering to columns (MySQL) with Perl (DBI)

Tags: arrays, perl, dbi

I am coding in Perl and i'm having some minor issue over here.

I have to refer to columns which I don't know the names of but I do know how many I will get back.

I am looking for a function like `bind_columns` but which operates with an array.

For example, `@Arr[0]` contains the data from column 1.

Comment: Huh? `@array = $sth->fetchrow_array();` Now you have all the columns from that row, in an array.

Comment: You can either use any of `fetchrow_array`, `fetchrow_arrayref`, or `fetchrow_hashref`, or you can use `bind_columns` with specific variable names (see http://blog.bluefeet.net/2011/08/using-dbi-effectively-bind_columns/ for an easy to follow example of this).  Unless your query is of the form `select * from table`, then you know how many columns you're choosing.

Comment: @Brian Roach: That's the solution right there. Post it as an answer (instead of a comment) and you've got my upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at how @Arr is being populated. Looks like you are getting it with something like:

```
@Arr = $sth->fetchrow(); #=> ['bar','baz']
```

Perhaps it would be better suited to get:

```
$row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref(); #=> {'name'=>'bar','title'=>'baz'}
$$row{'name'}; #=> 'bar'
```